# What's the difference between the Normal and Apocalyptic difficulties?

Tags: darksiders-2

Darksiders 2 doesn't seem to have any in-game info telling me exactly how the game difficulty will increase if I choose Apocalyptic instead of Normal difficulty. I've seen games handle this in a variety of different ways, such as upping monster health/damage, lowering drop rates of things like healing potions, or even sometimes entirely changing what types of enemies you see, like in Ninja Gaiden.

What **specific** effect does upping the difficulty have in this game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I've gathered, health and damage of enemies is significantly increased. (In some cases, up to twice the amount)

People seem to be having quite an easy time with the game, as long as you upgrade your weapons and focus on avoiding attacks.

If you are worried about the difficulty, you can always beat the game on normal. If you can collect all pieces of Abyssal Armor on one save, it carries over on the second playthrough.

Difficulty also affects the acquisition of specific achievements/trophies, such as defeating the game on Apocalypse difficulty.

Comment: I'm playing on Apocalpytic and it hasn't been too bad (other than when I ran into Gorewood at level 2). Mainly I'm just curious. I hate it when games don't tell you what things the difficulty level actually changes.

Answer (score 2):

When I clicked on change difficulty, it prompted me that changing the difficulty mid-session will result in being rewarded based on the lowest difficulty selected. So my guess is the drops will change if you select a harder difficulty, however I'm not certain because it may mean that choosing difficulty mid-session will result in rewards based to the lowest difficulty you've selected (**easy/normal/apocalyptic respectively*) in the start*.

Answer (score 1):

As the difficulties increase enemies have more health and do more damage and are more aggressive. The restart health and wrath recharge are different as well; so when you die in easy you start with more health and wrath, and on apocalyptic you revive with what you had. Nightmare difficulty is the same as apocalyptic but with only 1 life, so when you die that is it.

Comment: this is from a tweet from a developer.

Comment: Could you add a link to the tweet in your answer as source for this information?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that the enemies will be harder, not necasarilly better but will have more health and block more or something. There hits will do more damage as well. That is how games usually increase difficulty, I doubt any of the story will change.

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the response, Ben, but I'm looking for either facts posted by the developers/game manuals/whatever or someone's direct observations from playing both difficulties. I'm not very interested in speculation, since I understand the basic concept of what increasing the difficulty entails in various games and could make speculations myself. Basically, I'm looking for *specifics*, such as "Enemies have double health and deal double damage. Potion drops are less frequent. You run into beefy variant monsters with special attacks in some areas." Things like that.

Comment: @Sterno: That information might be useful to be stated in your question.

Comment: @Daenyth  Done!!

Answer (score 0):

In Darksiders II the quality item drop rate increases.
As well as other things mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but it seems that no weapons with health on hit or life steal drops on apocalyptic difficulty to use them on possesed weapons. Im in city of the dead now and have been farming 4 ape-cat-like (or whatever they are) mobs at frozen bay before...for a long time...not a single drop with those stats, so I had to stick with health on crit/crit chance/crit damage and defense/resist stats. Works pretty good, im doing over 9k damage with my glaive charge on crit (unstoppable tree helps a lot ;) and healing myself with rapid dmg dealing scythes combos (forward evade + razor wheel + flip saw ... generates wrath godly too). Hope this helps someone, have fun playing this beautiful game :-)

Comment: I've seen life on kill, but not life on hit. I'm only level 10 or so though.

Answer (score 0):

The enemies are way hard than on normal, Health Increased significantly and Damaged done by enemies have increased as well.
Apocalyptic mode also considers the drops after killing enemies which i guess is lowered.